# Can't boot to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, multi-boot

I was using windows 10 for two weeks, and then I installed [Need for Speed: Shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Need_for_Speed:_Shift), and it won't launch in Windows 10.

However I tried playing the game by booting into Windows 7, but after I click on Windows 7 on the boot screen, I get a black screen after a while the computer reboots.

I have:

- Windows 10 Pro 64bit
- Windows 7 integral 32bit

edit: oh nevermind this is regular for windows

Comment: How are you trying to get into Windows 7?  Dual boot or like? Try running Windows 7 as a Virtual Machine.

Comment: dual boot on a real machine i tried and it works on vm

Comment: If I post the VM solution above, will you find that helpfu?

Comment: Do not edit the title to say "solved". This is added automatically by the site when an answer is presented and the asker marks that answer as correct. Please read our help section to better understand the way this site works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this is regular i can boot into windows 7